# Explain ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am a beginner, so don't be amused by my questions. I think
`if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)` is used to check if the dataset is empty. But what exactly `[0]` signify in this case? Can you explain this statement in a little more detail?
And this one too.. `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());`

Comment: What about ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer but now i am confused which one to mark as Answer, you are all correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It gives you access to the first table of the `DataSet`. A `DataSet` holds an array of `DataTables`, and it can have 0, 1 or many of these `DataTables`. You access them just like any other array - by indexing into them.

If there were 2 `DataTables` in this `DataSet`, you could access the first one by using `ds.Tables[0]`, and the second one by `ds.Tables[1]`

The `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());` statement is adding a new row to the first `DataTable` in the `DataSet`. By calling `ds.Tables[0].NewRow()`, you are creating a new row that is associated to the first `DataTable` in the array.

Answer (score 5):

Here `ds` is an instance of [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). A DataSet may contain multiple instances of [Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx).

`ds.Tables[0]` **is accessing the first table** in the `Tables` collection. And `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count` is counting the rows on that first table.

Rows accesses the DataRow collection. The Add method creates one more row; however, you need to pass an instance of DataRow as the parameter. This DataRow object **must have the same structure (columns)** that the table, for this reason, you use the same table to create a new DataRoq: `ds.Tables[0].NewRow()`

Comment: What about ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());?

Comment: @user1856304 `Rows` accesses the Rows collection. The Add method creates one more row; however, you need to pass an instance of DataRow as the parameter. This DataRow object must have the same structure (columns) that the table, for this reason, you use the same table to create a new row: `ds.Tables[0].NewRow()`

Answer (score 2):

```
ds >>>>>>>>>>> Object of DataSet class from System.Data namespace
Tables[0] >>>> DataTable class object at index 0 inside ds object
Rows >>>>>>>>> RowCollection object which contain all the rows
Count >>>>>>>> Used to count no of rows inside the collection.
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be more than one table in dataset, by using ds.Tables[0] you are taking the first table.

Answer (score 0):

all above explanation is right .

but here are my 2 cents

ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count

before you use above statement , it's good if you check below condition

```
if (ds !=null && ds.Tables.count>0 )
```